# Python Bittrex api call

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, get, feed

I am new to python, and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out.
Basically I'm trying to have python call this api url and pull currency prices. I have it displaying the output of the url, but next I'd like to have it continuously call that api url and display on the next line down the current price, so I can basically use it as a live price ticker. Later I will try to send this output to a website to display live prices. I would like it to call the api url every 5 seconds or so. Here's what I have, but it's only displaying the prices once currently.

```
import urllib
feed = urllib.urlopen("https://bittrex.com/api/v1/public/getticker?market=BTC-SHIBE")
print feed.read()
raw_input()
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been working on this for a little over a week and I just don't know much about this language yet.

Comment: Since that URL is returning JSON, you might find [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads) useful ...

Comment: You probably need to spend some time with Flow Control, specifically the while loop: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement.  Also, `from time import sleep` to get access to a sleep function.

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` package is handy for this. As Zero says, bittrex returns data in JSON format, which `requests` handles nicely. So you will have to get the price from the dictionary you are given, found under the "result" key. How you want to display the resulting info is up to you.

Here is an example where I just print the BID/ASK/LAST dictionary as is and wait 5 seconds to get updated price info:

```
import time
import requests

while True:

    r = requests.get("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-DOGE")

    data = r.json()
    res = data["result"]

    print(res)
    time.sleep(5)
```

The output will look like this:

{'Bid': 4e-07, 'Ask': 4.1e-07, 'Last': 4.1e-07}

{'Bid': 4e-07, 'Ask': 4.1e-07, 'Last': 4.1e-07}

{'Bid': 4e-07, 'Ask': 4.1e-07, 'Last': 4.1e-07}

{'Bid': 4e-07, 'Ask': 4.1e-07, 'Last': 4.1e-07}